# Comment Template variables in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a comment template in Eclipse (CDT) that I use for function calls which looks like:

```
//****************************************************************************
//
// Function: ${enclosing_method}
//
// Purpose:  
//
// Parameters:
//
//****************************************************************************
```

My problem is that the `${enclosing_method}` template variable doesn't work MOST of the time, but other times it does and I have yet to figure out why.  I've tried using the comment template inside of the function and outside (on top of) the function definition even within the same header file.  I prefer it to be on top and have seen it work in that position but again I don't know why.

What prerequisites need to be met in order for the enclosing_method variable to place the name within the comment automagically?

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are [not the only one](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg18370.html) experiencing issues with this template.
Even in JDT (Java) there is a problem, since 2004! See [bug 76661](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76661).

It is however not entirely reproducible.

> Looked into this to try and find a reproducible case.  I can get it happen consistently if I add a new method to a class and then execute the template inside of the method before saving

So far, no patch in sight.